# Stop & being converted to &amp;

Tags: jquery

jQuery is converting `&` to `&amp;` 
How can I stop this

My code is this

```
$("#DeliverNewAddress").click(function(){
        var pageLink =  "{ordering.selectbillinglink}";
        alert(pageLink);
        var href = $('#selectAd').attr('href');
        window.location.href = pageLink; //causes the browser to refresh and load the requested url 
    });
```

im getting the url form this

```
<a href="{ordering.selectbillinglink}" id="selectAd"  class="selectAd" ></a>
```

and in the HTML renders fines

```
/checkout.php?xCmd=s3&xFrom=s2&xType=select&xAid=0&jssCart=057f4450ed29ab674e16d7488e72facd
```

but when I alert this it comes out like

```
/checkout.php?xCmd=s3&amp;xFrom=s2&amp;xType=select&amp;xAid=0&amp;jssCart=057f4450ed29ab674e16d7488e72facd
```

and breaks the checkout

Comment: It seems that text already contains `&amp;`. `&` does not get replaced by `&amp;`. It only appears correctly in the HTML because `&amp;` is the *HTML entitity* for `&`. How are you substituting the `{ordering.selectbillinglink}` occurrences?

Comment: It has to be encoded, which is necessary.  Why do you want yo show the url in `alert`?

Comment: I just added the alert to see what was being set.( this will be removed)..
Am i even approaching this right? All i really need to do is click the button #selectAD when the fake button is pressed  #DeliverNewAddress

Comment: To answer your question "am I approaching this right?", the answer is "no, not really". If that URL is intended to submit shopping cart data, you should be using an http POST rather than a GET, which means that you should have the fields in a form, and submit them rather than building up a query string.

Comment: Thanks guys .
I got it working in the end with
window.location.href =($('#selectAd').attr('href'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to escape the html in expression language

See the function  [fn:escapeXml](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html)

```
 ${fn:escapeXml(param:info)}
```

So you need to write

```
href="${fn:escapeXml(ordering.selectbillinglink)}"
```

where `fn` is the prefix for the taglib.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

[An Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_escapexml.htm)